# How to create multiple JPanels with JTextField input?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am currently working on my school project to practice vocabulary, I have a method in my GUI that creates new vocabulary and the name of the list, I wanted to create a button that adds more Panels with input fields just this prototype image.

[image: Prototype GUI]

My idea is that when the user clicks
`AddMoreButton` it will add one JPanel just like `P` Panel, then the user can write vocabulary to send it to my database, is it possible to create something that?, I tried looping the `P` panel but it did not not change, any help would be appreciated.

```
private JPanel SetUpCreate() {
        JPanel createPanel = new JPanel();
        nameListInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        termInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        defintionInput = new JTextField(INPUT_FIELD_WIDTH);
        p = new JPanel();
        doneCreate = new JButton("Done");
        doneCreate.addActionListener(new DoneCreateButtonAction());
        addMoreButton = new JButton("Add");
        addMoreButton.addActionListener(new AddMorePanelsListener());
        p.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        p.add(termInput);
        p.add(defintionInput);
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(p);
        createPanel.add(nameListInput);
        createPanel.add(p);
        createPanel.add(pane);
        createPanel.add(doneCreate);
        return createPanel;

    }
    private class DoneCreateButtonAction implements ActionListener {
        public DoneCreateButtonAction() {
            super();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String namelist = nameListInput.getText();
            String termglosa = termInput.getText();
            String defintionglosa = defintionInput.getText();
            try {
                if (model.createWordList(namelist) && (model.createGlosa(termglosa, defintionglosa))) {

                    cl.show(cardPanel, "home");

                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "skapelsen av listan fungerar ej.");

            }

        }

    }
private class AddMoreButtonAction implements ActionListener {
        public AddMoreButtonAction() {
            super();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



        }
    }
```

Comment: Separate the creation of one number JLabel and two JTextFields in a single method that your add button action listener can perform.

Answer (score 1):

As your code is not an [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I cannot provide further assistance than this:

Red part: Your main `JPanel` with BoxLayout
Green part: another `JPanel` with your `JTextField` in it.
Purple part: `JScrollPane`
Blue parts: custom `JPanels` with 2 panes in them, one on top for the number, one on the bottom for both `JTextField`s and icon, so I would say `GridBagLayout` or `BoxLayout` + `FlowLayout`
Orange part: `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout` or `FlowLayout`

Each time you clic on the `+` icon, you just create a new instance of the custom blue `JPanel` and that's it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is that you want to add another panel every time the user clicks the *Add* button and the panel to add contains fields for entering a word and its definition.

I see `JScrollPane` appears in the code you posted in your question. I think this is the correct implementation. In the below code, every time the user clicks the *Add* button I create a panel that contains the fields for a single word definition. This newly created panel is added to an existing panel that uses `GridLayout` with one column. Hence every time a new word definition panel is added, it is placed directly below the last word panel that was added and this `GridLayout` panel is placed inside a `JScrollPane`. Hence every time a word definition panel is added, the `GridLayout` panel height increases and the `JScrollPane` adjusts accordingly.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class MorPanel implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final String  ADD = "Add";
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPanel  vocabularyPanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String actionCommand = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case ADD:
                vocabularyPanel.add(createWordPanel());
                vocabularyPanel.revalidate();
                vocabularyPanel.repaint();
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                              actionCommand,
                                              "Unhandled",
                                              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public JButton createButton(String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    public JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton(ADD));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createMainPanel() {
        vocabularyPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        vocabularyPanel.add(createWordPanel());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(vocabularyPanel);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel createWordPanel() {
        JPanel wordPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel wordLabel = new JLabel("Enter Term");
        JTextField wordTextField = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel definitionLabel = new JLabel("Enter Term Definition");
        JTextField definitionTextField = new JTextField(10);
        wordPanel.add(wordLabel);
        wordPanel.add(wordTextField);
        wordPanel.add(definitionLabel);
        wordPanel.add(definitionTextField);
        return wordPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Vocabulary");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(480, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new MorPanel());
    }
}
```